# Is there a Formula for Binomial Series?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to learn more about the Binomial Probability Distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Consider the Binomial Probability Distribution:

$$P(X=k) = \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$$

Where:

- $X$ is the binomial random variable.
- $k$ is the number of successes in n independent trials.
- $n$ is the total number of trials.
- $p$ is the probability of success on a single trial.

Suppose I observe 100 "experiments" - in each of these experiments, I know the number of "successes" that occurred in each experiment, but I do not know how many trials were in each experiment. However, I know that the number of trials in each experiment was constant. E.g. Experiment 1 had $k$ = 33 Successes out of $n$ Trials, Experiment 2 had $k$ =55 Successes out of $n$ Trials... but I do not know the value of $n$. However, $n$ is the same in all Experiments.

Recall that in the case of a Discrete Probability Distribution, the Expected Value of a Random Variable can be written as:

$$E(X) = \sum x_i p(x_i)$$

$$E(X^2) = \sum x_i^2 p(x_i)$$

Based on this information, I could define the two following series:

- **Series 1:** We can write the Expected Value of $X$ as follows (even though we do not know the value of $n$ and $p$):

$$E(X) = \sum_{i=1}^{100} K_i * \binom{n}{K_i} * p^{K_i} * (1-p)^{n-K_i} = K_1 \binom{n}{K_1} p^{K_1} (1-p)^{n-K_1} + \cdots + K_{100} \binom{n}{K_{100}} p^{K_{100}} (1-p)^{n-K_{100}}$$

- **Series 2:** We can write the Expected Value of $X^2$ as follows (even though we do not know the value of $n$ and $p$):

$$E(X^2) = \sum_{i=1}^{100} K_i^{2} * \binom{n}{K_i} * p^{K_i} * (1-p)^{n-K_i} = K_1^{2} \binom{n}{K_1} p^{K_1} (1-p)^{n-K_1} + \cdots + K_{100}^{2} \binom{n}{K_{100}} p^{K_{100}} (1-p)^{n-K_{100}}$$

**My Question:** From First Principles (i.e. general properties of Random Variables and  Binomial Distribution), I know that for large values of $n$:

- Series 1  converges to $np$ , i.e. $E(X) \to np$
- Series 2 converges to $np(1-p) + (np)^2$ , i.e. $E(X^2) \to np(1-p) + (np)^2$

**But how exactly can we simplify Series 1 and Series 2 to mathematically show that they are converge to these amounts? Do these series belong to a well-known class of series that allows for some kind of simplification?**

Thanks!

**Note:** Regarding Series 2, this can be seen as follows. In general, $Var(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2$. And in a Binomial Distribution $Var(X) = np(1-p)$. Thus, through algebraic manipulation, we can derive a formula for $E(X^2)$

Comment: What is $K_i$ defined as?

Comment: @Alan Abraham: thank you so much for your reply! $K_i$ is the result of the i-th experiment (i.e. the number of successes within the i-th experiment)

Comment: Your question is confusing. For instance, at the beginning of your post $X$ is a Binomial random variable with parameters $n$,$p$ but not any more later. Are the $K_i$ deterministic ? How exactly is defined the $X$ of the second half of your post in terms of the result of the experiments ? What remains random in it if the $K_i$'s are deterministic quantities ? You should consider clarifying all this, and it would be far easier to answer your question.

Comment: @Calz : thank you for your reply! I apologize for the notation, I will try to correct it. My question was about learning how to simplify the series ... I added some of the other information for context and background. perhaps it would have been better not to do this...

Comment: I believe that the series you have written can't be simplified because the $K_i$'s could be anything. In particular, if I assume that $K_i=C$ for all $i$, the first sum become, with $R$ the number of experiment,  $Rc\binom{n}{K_i} * p^{C} * (1-p)^{n-C}$ which cannot converges (as $R\to\infty$) to what you are expecting. I beleeve this is because you are misinterpreting the definition of the expectation, in particular due to the fact that the definition of $X$ is not clear.